# Where do I look for issues with a local AD user not being able to activate O365 on any machine

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

Here is our really weird situation.  AD on prem, using Exchange Online w/ 365.  We have an unmanaged auto machine that stopped authenticating from the domain joined machine to office 365.  Won't connect to Exchange Online, activate office, nothing.  Started with deleting credentials, restore from backup from before the incident, reinstall office.  Getting "Sorry we are having temporary server issues" instead of the modern auth pop up.  The last weird thing is that if I install office for this account on a machine that is not domain joined, everything activates fine on the same vlan through the same firewall. All other accounts are working for local AD users.  I don't see anything in the local event logs that shows me a failure for logging in either.  I'm kind of at a loss, so any help would be great.

Comment: Hi. Can you erase the computer account and retry, and make sure it use the correct DNS, the same as your other machines

Comment: Yea, I set the VM to a known working static with the same result.  Had the same result on another machine known working (mine)

Comment: Open a support case from your Office 365 tenant. It's free. They'll help you solve the problem.